# Why has comma been used after "been" in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation

I read an example in Merriam Webster dictionaries which was:

His son has been, in politics a nonstarter.

Why was comma used after "been" not after "in politics"? Because in this sort of sentences, we usually use it after a complete clause to introduce another clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that an additional comma is necessary, after "in politics":

> His son has been, in politics, a nonstarter.

In that way, "in politics" is separated from the rest of the sentence, and it gets an accent: maybe he was OK in the rest of his life, but he was no material for politics.